# Why isn't the description field synchronized at different Electrum wallet?

Tags: wallet, electrum

I use Electrum as my BitCoin wallet, and install it on both home PC and office PC.

I fill in "Description" field and send some Bitcoin on the office PC BitCoin wallet, it's OK.

The Electrum wallet on home PC can display the record except "Description" field, why?

1:  Is "Description" field  only for local record on Electrum wallet ?

2:  Doesn't a Bitcoin transaction record incude "Description" field?

**Image 1**

[image]

**Image 2**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Bitcoin transaction holds no Metadata beyond what is required for moving coins. Any descriptions, labels, or other such information is purely handled by the wallet, and synchronizing it is up to the wallet.

Electrum does not synchronize any such data, so you will only see it on one device.